# How to add + and - to accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have implemented a basic accordion, I need to add + and - to accordion.

If the accordion is open then '-' should get else '+'

This is what tried:

JS:

```
$('.info').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/)

Comment: I would do it with css and an "active" class. could also do the slideup/down with css.

Comment: @KevinB : Can you please help me with your implemetation demo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add plus minus symbol to a bootstrap accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242422/how-to-add-plus-minus-symbol-to-a-bootstrap-accordion)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/1/

Comment: similar to http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css  pseudo elements as follows:

CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle::after {
  content:"+";
}
.accordion-toggle.open::after {
  content:"-";
}
```

JS:

```
$('.info').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass("open");
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/5/)