# Bootstrap nested accordion font-awesome icons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I've a 3 level nested bootstrap accordion which is working fine, but I want a change in the *panel-heading div* where I can use a font-awesome icon `fa fa-chevron-down` when the accordion is opened (Without affecting the nested accordions) and `fa fa-chevron-right` when accordion is collapsed. I'm using this code to changing the icon:

```js
$('div.panel-collapse.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-right").removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
  $(this).parent().find('.panel-heading').css('background', '#0271BC');
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
  $(this).parent().find('.panel-heading').css('background', '#02A4EF');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="#aspnetcore" class="accordion-toggle tutorial-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading outer web">
      <h4 class="panel-title fonter font-light-text">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> Getting Starting with ASP.NET Core 1.0
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="aspnetcore" class="panel-collapse collapse outer-arrow">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group" id="webdevelopment">
          <a href="#frontend" class="accordion-toggle tutorial-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#webdevelopment">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading middle-link-web">
                <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> Front-End
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="frontend" class="panel-collpase collapse outer-arrow">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="panel-group" id="webdevelopment">
                    <a asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Grunt" class="accordion-toggle lab-link">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading middle-link">
                          <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                            Grunt Task Runner
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#angular" class="accordion-toggle tutorial-panel-heading inner-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#frontend">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading middle-link-web">
                          <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> Angular
                            2
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="angular" class="panel-collpase collapse">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <a asp-controller="Web" asp-action="Angular" class="accordion-toggle lab-link">
                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading middle-link">
                                  <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                                    Introduction to Angular 2
                                  </h4>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>

                    <a class="accordion-toggle lab-link">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading middle-link">
                          <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                            LESS and SASS <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="#backend" class="accordion-toggle tutorial-panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#webdevelopment">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading middle-link-web">
                <h4 class="panel-title font-light-text">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> Back-End
                </h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But this code also change the icons of the nested accordions which are not opened yet. Is there any better way to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post you html code also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I prefer to use examples form the Bootstrap documentation and toggle icons by CSS.

And I've added Font Awesome icons as a content of [the `:after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

---

### Bootstrap 4

Based on the [Accordion example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example).

Please check the result: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/QQOZRe)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.mb-0 > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.mb-0 > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.mb-0 > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body">

        <div id="accordion-1">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                  Item 1 > 1
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
              <div class="card-body">

                  <div id="accordion-1-1">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-1">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-1">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 1
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-2">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-2">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 2
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1-3">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-3">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 3
                          </a>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 3
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-2">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-2">
                  Item 1 > 2
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-labelledby="heading-1-2">
              <div class="card-body">
                Text 1 > 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-2">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-3">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Bootstrap 3

Based on the [Accordion example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion).

Please check the result: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/xYPyeq)  •  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/1wx4ubvc/)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.panel-title > a:after {
  content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.panel-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                  Item 1 > 1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1">
              <div class="panel-body">

                  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1-1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-1">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 1
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-2">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-2">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 2
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-2">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-1-3">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1-1" href="#collapse-1-1-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1-3">
                            Item 1 > 1 > 3
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapse-1-1-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-1-3">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Text 1 > 1 > 3
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1-2">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapse-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-2">
                  Item 1 > 2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1-2">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Text 1 > 2
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-2">
          Item 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-3">
          Item 3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Text 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. But I'm just a little bit hesitated while using Glyph-icons as they are no more in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @JanshairKhan Not sure I understand correctly. Do you need to change FontAwesome icons on Glyph-icons?

Comment: No, as you recommended to use Glyph-Icons over FontAwesome, I think this will be a little bit cumbersome in the future when I'll migrate toward Bootstrap 4 as Bootstrap 4 only support FontAwesome.

Comment: @JanshairKhan I do not recommend to use Glyphicons. My code uses Font Awesome. Look at my CSS. I have added icons as a content of   [the `:after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

Comment: when using bootstrap 4, you need to change the styles from panel-title to card-header

Comment: @sksallaj Thank you for the comment. I've added a solution for Bootstrap 4 too.

Answer (score 1):

Found an existing jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/r6eaw/12/
and with a little copy-paste, one with a nested accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/3979/

One of the issues with your code is that you are nesting div's in anchor (`<a/>`) tags. That is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but your code is not working. :(

Comment: Could you create the problem in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example, with this, initially show the icons correctly using Jquery and Bootstrap.

*¡May it be very helpful to you!*

```js
$(function(){
 $('.panel-title a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', this, function(event) {
  
  $('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').find('i').removeClass('fa-plus-circle').addClass('fa-minus-circle');
  });

  $('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
   $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').find('i').removeClass('fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa-plus-circle');
  });

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<!-- Panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="item001">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#detail001" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="detail001">
      <div class="title">Title 1 <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="detail001" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="item001">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/ Panel -->

<!-- Panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="item002">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#detail002" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="detail002">
      <div class="title">Title 2 <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="detail002" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="item002">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/ Panel -->

</div>
```