# Bootstrap nested accordion with inline links

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using a snippet from the question [Bootstrap nested accordion font-awesome icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037274/bootstrap-nested-accordion-font-awesome-icons) which enables a nested accordion using Twitter's bootstrap.

I want to be able to have a link to another endpoint within the accordion header, however due to the `after` property the link is not inline and is instead being pushed down below the accordion header (`display: block`).

Based on [this snippet](https://codepen.io/432sdf/pen/oNXqazq), I want to have the "I'm a link, but not inline" `span` to be in the place of the "I'm inline, but not a link" `span`.

Can somebody assist me with the correct CSS to use?

Comment: Move the span outside the anchor tag and give it it's own anchor tag. Post your code here to get better response.

Comment: The second example ("I'm a link, but not inline") does have the span outside the anchor tag.