# Font Awesome arrow icons not showing with 'content:\' (Bootstrap accordion)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I've been trawling through answers to similar questions and have changed my code multiple times, but anything I try seems to make no difference.

I'm using Bootstrap and have built a small accordion, I want to implement up/down arrows that change when each panel is open/closed.

Here is the CSS:

```
    main #exhibit .spec-care {
       position: relative;
    }

    main #exhibit .spec-care::after {
       content: "\f107";
       right: 0px;
       font-family: "FontAwesome 5 Free";
       position: absolute;
       font-weight: 900;
    }

    main #exhibit .spec-care[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
       content: "\f106";
    }
```

I'm calling:

```
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and finally I just see this in place of where the arrows should be:

'f107' (or f106)

Any help would be great. thanks.

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037274/bootstrap-nested-accordion-font-awesome-icons

Comment: Thanks, I did read this earlier. Do you mean the part where they say to change the heading class from panel title to card header? Not sure...

Comment: Can you try `font-family:Font Awesome\ 5 Free;` ? It's in my understanding the font-family should be perfectly the same.

Comment: no luck there either unfortunately Tim.