# How to switch label to + or - if collapse class is collapsed or not?

Tags: css

I need to open/close rows of a table and modify the `+` sign accordingly.

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c55s6gLo/)

For some reason I do not know, it is not working.
It does in my page.

I really wish the plus sign to change to a minus when one clicks on it to open the `<td>`.

I tried working on this code: [How to add plus minus symbol to a bootstrap accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242422/how-to-add-plus-minus-symbol-to-a-bootstrap-accordion). But I found difficulties when using it in my code.

Comment: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c55s6gLo/1/) you can assign other code to the click event like; `$('#1').removeClass('collapse')` and `$('#1').addClass('collapse')` etc.

Comment: I think the approach you have used for accordion using tables is wrong...you should take one of these http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-only-accordion/...using table layouts is wrong

Comment: @Geeky hi, thanks, i am not sure in that link, it heads me to a page that i don't think is focused on this issue. Maybe wrong link?

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst thanks for this update! exactly what I am looking for. Thing is that the sign change, but the td does not open

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst ok, because I applied the change before yours applied. I'm adding bootstrap.js and see

Comment: @Roy_Dorsthorst sorry for this spam. but your code works. If you want I'll be glad to upvote your answer (: and thanks!

Comment: If you want a css only accordion that link helps you.I wanted to say tables are not the right approach for accordions

Comment: @Geeky thanks again for the hint, yes I know and I read it too but I couldn't use other approaches at this time. Need to use tables. That link opens to "8 Ways How Freelancers Can Launch Your Startup" and I do not know if it right. I mean, it is not talking of css, it is about another topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the '+' into a '-' and vice versa you can use if statements and the `.text()` method to change the text.

To show the table below with the according id, you again can use if statements to check if the data-target which you've given. Use the `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods to add and remove classes to an element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c55s6gLo/4/) with working example.